# Using consecutive while(cin >> input) successfully

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

My first while loop executes, until I enter a non-number to terminate it. Then, instead of `while(cin >> cel)` executing, it is skipped, leading the program to terminate/finish. I have tried everything including clearing the "cin bit" as described in another similiar question with no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main() {
    double fah = 0;
    cout << "Enter a fahrenheit value:\n";
    while (cin >> fah) { // executes until a non-number input is entered
        cout << fah << "F == " << fah_to_cel(fah) << "C\n";
    }
    // tried cin.clear();  here
    // tried cin.clear(ios_base::eofbit); here
    double cel = 0;
    cout << "Enter a celcius value:\n";
    while(cin >> cel) { // executes until a non-number input is entered
        cout << cel << "C == " << cel_to_fah(cel) << "F\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to `clear()` to reset the error flags and then `ignore()` to discard previous input up to and including the newline. I'll link a duplicate question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were correct to call `cin.clear()`. That resets the error flags of `cin`, which you need to do before you can perform any more input operations. But you need to do one more thing. When input fails, whatever characters `cin` was trying to read remain in the input buffer. So when you try to collect input again (after clearing the error), it will fail again. So you need to remove the data that was left in the buffer. You can do that like this:

```
std::streamsize amount_to_ignore = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();
std::cin.ignore(amount_to_ignore, '\n');
```

This tells `cin` to discard all characters in its buffer until it finds a newline character (which should be in there from when you last pressed the enter key).

This is, in my opinion, a very clunky and error prone way to do user input. I would suggest that you exclusively use `std::getline` when reading from `cin`, which should never fail (except in the unlikely event of a memory allocation failure). And then parsing the resulting string manually, which gives you a lot more control over the form of the input.